# A profinite group that is not finite is not countable

Tags: group-theory, cardinals, profinite-groups

I am trying to show the well-known fact that if a profinite group $G$ is not finite, then is not countable (i.e. $|G|\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$). There are many ways of proving this fact but I am interested in the following reasoning.

Since $G$ is a profinite group we have that it is an inverse limit of finite groups with the discrete topology
$$G=\lim\limits_{\substack{\longleftarrow\\ i\in I}} G_i\subseteq \prod\limits_{i\in I} G_i.$$

We also have that $I$ is infinite because $G$ is not finite.

I will assume that the maps $\varphi_{i,j}: G_i\longrightarrow G_j$ are surjective.

It follows that $|G_j||\ker\varphi_{i,j}|=|G_i|$. And since, $|\ker\varphi_{i,j}|\geq 2$, it follows that for any $i\geq j$, $|G_i|\geq 2|G_j|$.

From this, I would like to deduce that $|G|\geq |2^{\aleph_0}|$.

Given that $|G|\geq |G_i|$ for any $i\in I$, I believe it follows that
$$|G|\geq 2^{|I|}.$$
Because for any $j\in I$, $$|G|\geq \prod\limits_{\substack{i\in I\\ i\geq j}} |\ker \varphi_{i,j}||G_j|\geq \prod\limits_{\substack{i\in I\\ i\geq j}} 2.$$

$|G|\geq 2^{|I|}$ clearly implies that $|G|\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

But I don't know if my argument is sufficient or even correct.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Take a sequence of open finite index subgroups $G\supset H_n\supsetneq H_{n+1}$ (the intersections of kernel of some $G\to G_i$). Once you have chosen $x_n\in G/H_n$ you have $|H_n/H_{n+1}|\ge 2$ choices for $x_{n+1}$, and any sequence of choices converges to an element of $\varprojlim G/H_n$, whence as a set $\{0,1\}^{\aleph_0}$ embeds into $\varprojlim G/H_n$, which is a quotient of $G$.

Comment: Can you be more precise on how can I get the sequence of $H_n$? 
What do you mean by the intersection of kerles of some $G\rightarrow G_i$?